EF Core - Nested property not appearing in Json
I am working on Odata API with .NET. I am facing an issue with the implementation of one of my endpoints. I have a nested array that is not being returned in the JSON response. The /software service has two methods , getAll() and getById(int id). I have entities called Software, SoftwareVersion, Computer, and ComputerSoftwareVersion which translates many to many relationship between computers and software versions. I am trying to show for each software , the list of versions and the servers on which they are installed. Below is the definition of my classes,the mappings I implemented and the service implementation. Unfortunately, I do not see the installations array in the json responses in the browser (as if the field does not exist in the data model).
CLASS DEFINITION

namespace Data.Entities
{
    public class Computer
    {
        // COMPUTER BLOCK
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string serial { get; set; }
        public string otherserial { get; set; }

        public string uuid { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public Boolean? is_deleted { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SoftwareVersion> SoftwareVersions { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<ComputerSoftwareVersion> ComputerSoftwareVersions { get; set; }
}


namespace Data.Custom
{
    public class CustomComputer
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string serial { get; set; }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }


    }
}



namespace Data.Entities
{
    public class Software
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Boolean? is_deleted { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }

        public DateTime? date_creation { get; set; }

        //public int softwares_id { get; set; }

        public int softwarecategories_id { get; set; }
        public virtual SoftwareCategorie SoftwareCategorie { get; set; }

        public int manufacturers_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }

        public int entities_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Entitie Entitie { get; set; }

        public int groups_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SoftwareVersion> SoftwareVersions { get; set; }

    }
}



namespace Data.Entities
{
    public class SoftwareVersion
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }


        public int softwares_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Software Software { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection <Computer> Computers { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ComputerSoftwareVersion> ComputerSoftwareVersions { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace Data.Custom
{
    public class CustomSoftware
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string entity { get; set; }
        public string publisher { get; set; }
        public string group { get; set; }

        public  string software_category { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<CustomSoftwareVersion> versions { get; set; }
    }
}



namespace Data.Custom
{
    public class CustomSoftwareVersion
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public  IEnumerable<CustomComputerSoftwareVersion> installations { get; set; }



    }
}


using System;

namespace Data.Custom
{
    public class CustomComputerSoftwareVersion
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string hosting_area { get; set; }

    }
}


*** COMPUTER MAPPING***

      public class ComputerMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Computer>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Computer> builder)
            {
    
                builder.HasMany(c => c.SoftwareVersions)
          .WithMany(t => t.Computers)
          .UsingEntity<ComputerSoftwareVersion>(x => x.HasOne(x => x.SoftwareVersion).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.softwareversions_id).IsRequired(true),
                                x => x.HasOne(x => x.Computer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.items_id).IsRequired(true),
                                x => x.ToTable("glpi_items_softwareversions"));
    
                builder.ToTable("computers");
    
            }
        }
    }

SOFTWARE VERSION MAPPING
{
    public class SoftwareVersionMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SoftwareVersion>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SoftwareVersion> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.id);


            builder.HasOne(c => c.Software).WithMany(l => l.SoftwareVersions).HasForeignKey(c => c.softwares_id).IsRequired(false);


            builder.HasMany(c => c.Computers)
       .WithMany(t => t.SoftwareVersions)
       .UsingEntity<ComputerSoftwareVersion>(x => x.HasOne(x => x.Computer).WithMany(l=>l.ComputerSoftwareVersions).HasForeignKey(x => x.items_id).IsRequired(true),
                             x => x.HasOne(x => x.SoftwareVersion).WithMany(l => l.ComputerSoftwareVersions).HasForeignKey(x => x.softwareversions_id).IsRequired(true),
                             x => x.ToTable("glpi_items_softwareversions"));

            builder.ToTable("softwareversions");
        }
    }
}

COMPUTER SOFTWARE MAPPING
{
    public class ComputerSoftwareVersionMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ComputerSoftwareVersion>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ComputerSoftwareVersion> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.id);

            builder.HasOne(c => c.SoftwareVersion).WithMany(l => l.ComputerSoftwareVersions).HasForeignKey(c => c.softwareversions_id).IsRequired(true);
            builder.HasOne(c => c.Computer).WithMany(l => l.ComputerSoftwareVersions).HasForeignKey(c => c.items_id).IsRequired(false);


            builder.ToTable("items_softwareversions");
        }
    }
}

SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION
public IQueryable<CustomSoftware> GetById(int id)
        {
            return _db
                .Where(s => s.id == id)
                .Where(s => s.is_deleted == false)
                .Include(s => s.SoftwareVersions)
                    .ThenInclude(d => d.Computers)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.ComputerWsusInfo)
                            .ThenInclude(c => c.ComputerDetailDatacenter)
                .Select(s => new CustomSoftware
                {
                    id = s.id,
                    name = s.name,
                    entity = s.Entitie.name,
                    publisher = s.Manufacturer.name,
                    group = s.Group.name,
                    software_category = s.SoftwareCategorie.completename,
                    versions = s.SoftwareVersions.Select(d => new CustomSoftwareVersion
                    {
                        name = d.name,
                        installations = d.Computers.Select(x => new CustomComputerSoftwareVersion
                        {
                            name = x.name,
                            status = x.State.name,
                            hosting_area = x.ComputerWsusInfo.ComputerDetailDatacenter.name
                        }) 
                    })
                });
        }

I am able to see all the properties in the browser except for the installations property. I tried changing the type returned to 'object', hence eliminating all the custom entities. It worked but for getAll method the query times out. I actually want to keep the format of IQueryable as it is consistent with the rest of my endpoints. I also logged the query generated by LINQ and I saw the joins between all the tables. For some reason , I am unable to see the installations array.
Thank you for your time!
Regards!

It looks as if you are trying to serialize results directly from reads through Entity Framework.  This isn't a good design.  You should have one or more data transfer objects that mirror your entity objects.  The array types inside the data transfer objects can be arrays or List.  Then the serializer will behave correctly.
i.e.
namespace Data.DTOs
{
    public class SoftwareVersionDto
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }


        public int softwares_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Software Software { get; set; }

        public List <Computer> Computers { get; set; }

        public List<ComputerSoftwareVersion> ComputerSoftwareVersions {  get; set; }
    }
}

You will copy the entity values into the DTO, and then serialize the DTO via your endpoint.
